# Variable se reinicie o tome el valor de 0 para guardar ese valor nuevamente, en un arreglo. C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda, estoy haciendo un ejercicio en c++, el cual consiste en darle horas de trabajo a ciertos trabajadores (5 trabajadores). Tengo un arreglo que guarda las horas de cada trabajador, digamos Juan trabajó 1 hora diaria, desde el lunes hasta el viernes, serian 7 horas, pero a la hora de guardar en el arreglo con la variable total, se suma las horas del trabajador anterior con el del siguiente. Y no se que hacer para que la variable total reiniciarla para que en cada vuelta pueda ser guardada las horas de cada trabajador de forma independiente, le mando un saludo a todos, gracias.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    string a[5]={"Juan","Pedro","Luis","Goku","Chabelo"};
    string diaz[7]={"lunes","martes","miercoles","jueves","viernes","sabado","domingo"};
    int h=0;
    int ht[5];
    int total=0;


    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"Trabajador: "<<a[i]<<endl;
        for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
            cout<<"Horas trabajadas el día "<<diaz[j]<<endl;
            cin>>h;
            total=total+h;
            ht[i]=total;
        }

    }

    for(int x=0; x<5; x++) {
     cout<<a[x]<<ht[x]<<endl;
        }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: después de terminar el for interno `for(int j=0; j<7; j++){ }` puedes poner `total = 0;`

Comment: Gracias @OscarG Funcionó muy bien, saludos compañero

Answer (score 0):

para reiniciar tu contador de horas , cada vez que vuelva a iterar en un nuevo trabajador asignar 0 a la variable total.

```
    //Ingresar horas de trabajo diarias
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    cout<<"Trabajador: "<<a[i]<<endl;
    for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
        cout<<"Horas trabajadas el día "<<diaz[j]<<endl;
        cin>>h;
        total=total+h;
        ht[i]=total;
    }
    //Reiniciando las horas de trabajo
    total=0; //Esta es la instrucción que faltó
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mover al interior del bucle más externo la definición de la variable que acumula valores:

```
// int total=0; /* aquí no */

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

    // A cada vuelta del bucle, 'total' se redefinirá con valor cero.
    int total=0;

    cout<<"Trabajador: "<<a[i]<<endl;
    for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
        cout<<"Horas trabajadas el día "<<diaz[j]<<endl;
        cin>>h;
        total=total+h;
        ht[i]=total;
    }
}
```

Se considera una buen práctica que las variables estén tan cerca de su punto de uso como sea posible, por lo que este cambio sería positivo también por ese motivo.